# Twitter API - How do you get a full list of Twitter's Moments

Tags: twitter

Unless I'm missing something, In the [Twitters Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-moments) it only shows you how to use and fetch JSON from a single Twitter Moment. Can you fetch an array / list of all trending Twitter Moments?

It shows in their example in their docs

```
GET https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https://twitter.com/i/moments/650667182356082688
```

would return

```
  {
  "url": "https://twitter.com/i/moments/650667182356082688",
    "title": "The Obamas' wedding anniversary",
    "html": "<a class=\"twitter-moment\" href=\"https://twitter.com/i/moments/650667182356082688\">The Obamas&#39; wedding anniversary</a>\n<script async src=\"//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>",
    "width": 550,
    "height": null,
    "type": "rich"
    "cache_age": "3153600000",
    "provider_name": "Twitter",
    "provider_url": "https://twitter.com",
    "version": "1.0"
  }
```

I'd prefer a non-embedded version of this but can work with it if I only get a url to the embedded version

Answer (score 0):

There's no API for working with Moments right now (and it is not currently on the [API roadmap](https://trello.com/b/myf7rKwV/twitter-api-platform-roadmap)). The only function that is exposed is the oEmbed capability to embed Moments on other sites, and that does indeed require you have have the URL to the relevant Moment from the website (or from the share link in the app).

Comment: any updates on this? I saw collections in the docs, but that's different. Otherwise, is there another place to submit feature requests for the site? Creating a moment on the site is pretty difficult once you get beyond a dozen tweets.

Comment: Yes, you can suggest developer platform features at https://twitterdevfeedback.uservoice.com - I’m not aware of any current priority to add Moment publishing but we have our new Developer Labs program that is piloting new features.